# How to use mysql FULLTEXT Search with WHERE in multiple fields using OR?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am using mysql FULLTEXT Search, `innodb` table engine.
search term : `tom`

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('tom' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND is_enabled = 1  AND category = 100 OR category = 200 ORDER BY seeders DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

above query gives `550` records, expected records are `6`

but if i search for each category separately.
searching in `category 100`

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('tom' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND is_enabled = 1  AND category = 100 ORDER BY seeders DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

gives `5` records

and searching in `category 200`

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('tom' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND is_enabled = 1  AND category = 200 ORDER BY seeders DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

gives `1` record.

so i am expecting records `6`, by combining 5+1 but i am getting 550, even those records which doesn't have word `tom` in it.

---

Another Issue, is 
searching in `category` or `sub_category` in same query for word `tom`

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('tom' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND is_enabled = 1  AND sub_category = 101 OR category = 200 ORDER BY seeders DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

gives `550` records. expected records are `6`

so how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

i have found solution. the query should be

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('tom' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND is_enabled = 1  AND (category = 100 OR category = 200) ORDER BY seeders DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

notice, the `OR` operator is in brackets

and 2nd query issue, searching in two fields using OR becomes

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('tom' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND is_enabled = 1  AND (sub_category = 101 OR category = 200) ORDER BY seeders DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: well, it was sort of obvious that you had to apply proper grouping to your conditions. Since the fix is so trivial why don't you consider removing this question altogether? It has no value for future readers in the actual Full Text Search mention because primarily it deals with the ability to construct proper SQL queries.